# Web scraping values inside of <div>

Tags: python, html, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm new to python and web scraping, and recently I'm facing a real challenge (at least for me hahahah)

I have this table in which every value is stored in a  with this configuration:

`<div row="15" column="1" style="font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;border-color: transparent;left: 100px; top: 476px; width: 53px; height: 34px;" class="sf-element-table-cell flex-justify-end flex-align-start  sfc-value-cell sfpc-even-column sfpc-odd-row"><div class="cell-text">5</div></div>`

I cannot share the URL since its a company internal url

My idea here is to retrieve the class="cell-text" of every "cell" and add to a dictionary or directly to a csv file, but I don't know how to do it.

Ex: The 5 in 'div class="cell-text">5<'

This table has 46 columns and close to 50,000 rows. Is it more practical to scrape it cell by cell or try to use the export feature of the page? When you right click the table there is a option to export it as a csv file and I guess its possible to navigate it using selenium.

Comment: Are all 50,000 rows shown in the web page? If so, you could scrape it with Selenium, but it may be slow. Downloading to a CSV is probably better, although automating that may be tricky.

Comment: If this is internal coimpany data, can't you ask for an API instead of having to scrape?

Comment: From your example you want to get the '5'?

Comment: yes, it would be the 5

Comment: @Barmar I tried to get an API but didn't get any answer of the responsables. Testing here, only a few rows appear each time, when I scroll down or up the shown "cells" change in the inspection tab

Comment: @Barmar I tought that downloading should be faster, but since I've never done something like this, I tiught it was worth asking

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium, you could try selecting each column at a time and iterating trough all the cells of that column to get the text of each cell.

```
driver.get('your_url')
data = {}
for number in range(1, 47):
    column_cells = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f'//div[@column="{number}"]')
    cells = [cell.text for cell in column_cells]
    # cells = [cell.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'cell-text').text for cell in column_cells]
    data[f'Column {number}'] = cells # creates a new value with the number of the column
       # and adds the list with the cells text to that value
```

If the first line with the variable cells doesn't get the right text, delete it and uncomment the second line.